# Retrieve all excel cell names within given range having perticular color background

Tags: excel, matlab

I am working on excel data, with in a specific range(B16:K400) there are few cells that have blue color back ground. I need to take out those value and save them to a variable.

I have tried and succeeded getting values from individual cells.

```
excel = actxserver('Excel.Application');
excel.Visible = true;
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(filename);
rgb = workbook.Worksheets.Item(sheetname).Range(cell).Interior.Color;
```

but, I can work one cell at a time. by doing for-loop I can do for a given range of cell.
I am interested to collect the cell Names having  same color background(let it be red colour) in one step.

It would be great if some one can suggest me, Thank you in advance

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?  If you're using a version prior 2002, you'll have to use a loop, other wise you use the "Find" function to find cells with specific formats.  Take a look at this site: https://excel.tips.net/T002396_Finding_Cells_Filled_with_a_Particular_Color.html